# Context processors, passing a session which doesn't exist

Tags: python, django, session

Hay All, I've got a simple context processor which looks within a session and if a 'user' key exists. If it does i want to return it to the template.

Here's my context Processor

```
def get_user_details(request):
    user = request.session['user']
    data = {
        'user':user
    }
    return data
```

and here is a sample view

```
def render_home(request):
    return render_to_response("home", context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

If the session['user'] doesn't exists, i want it to silently fail, or return False or Null.

Because the key doesnt exist within the session, i get a KeyError.

Any idea's how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a default value like `None` this way: `request.session.get('user', None)`. Just like in normal Python dicts.

Comment: This is the best solution, it also cuts the context processor down to 3 lines. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
user = request.session.get('user', None)
```

or,

```
user = None
if 'user' in request.session:
    user = request.session['user']
```

Comment: The top one is the one i used, unfortunately THC4k got there first, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_user_details(request):
    try:
        user = request.session['user']
    except KeyError:
        return
    data = {
        'user':user
    }
    return data
```

Or if you want to catch it further away, do this instead:

```
def render_home(request):
    try:
        return render_to_response("home", context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    except KeyError:
        return
```